# Как объяснить постановку запятой перед тире в данном предложении при помощи справочника Розенталя?

Tags: пунктуация

Необыкновенная выносливость белых медведей, свойственная им от природы, — неразгаданная тайна для многих поколений истинных исследователей непознанного.

Answer (score 2):

Запятыми обособлен определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова. Тире не отменяет второй запятой.

Обособление запятыми основывается на правиле:

> Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются
>   с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные
>   причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так
>   называемые определительные обороты), стоящие после существительного
>   или субстантивированного слова...

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91

Тире поставлено по другому правилу:

> Тире ставится между подлежащим [здесь: выносливость] и сказуемым [здесь: тайна] *при отсутствии связки*, если
>   оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме
>   именительного падежа.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108

О сочетании получившихся двух знаков:

> При «встрече» внутри предложения запятой и тире сначала ставится
>   запятая, а затем тире.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175

Answer (score 1):

Запятая «закрывает» определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова; тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым.